# Python Refactoring from Static class?

Tags: python-3.x, refactoring

All over my code I use a python “static” class like this:
    curStatus = StaticClass.getStat()

where

```
class StaticClass:
    @staticmethod
    def getStat () -> str:
        return "noSimulate"
```

But now I have a refactor issue where sometimes SIMULATE is TRUE or FALSE

```
SIMULATE: bool = false
```

If Simulate is true, I want staticmethod.getStat() to be a different method. 
But I only want to check SIMULATE once and use polymorphism to do the rest.

& I don’t want to refactor the whole code base.

How can I change StaticClass method by just checking SIMULATE once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this info: [python3-patterns](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)

and created these two .py files:
Testing.polymorphism

```
# https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html
SIMULATE:bool = True

# class myBase(object):
class myBase:
    @staticmethod
    def factory(sim:bool) :
        return yesSim() if sim else myBase()

    @staticmethod
    def getDroneStatus() -> str:
        print("myBase.getDroneStatus()")
        return "UNITIALIZED! FAIL!!"

    @staticmethod
    def getStaticStatus() -> str:
        print("myBase.getStaticStatus()")
        return "UNITIALIZED! FAIL!!"


class yesSim(myBase):

    @staticmethod
    def getDroneStatus() -> str:
        return "yesSim"


GSCRAMtcp = myBase.factory(SIMULATE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myTCP = myBase.factory(SIMULATE)
    print(myTCP.getStaticStatus())
    print(myTCP.getDroneStatus())
```

and this testfile:

```
from Testing.polymorphism.testPolymorph import GSCRAMtcp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(GSCRAMtcp.getDroneStatus())
    print(GSCRAMtcp.getStaticStatus())
```